# Laravel ORM one to many in one array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm

In Laravel 4.2, I have this models

```
// models ticket.php
class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    public function feedback()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Feedback');
    }
}

// models/feedback.php
class Feedback extends Eloquent {

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ticket');
    }
}
```

**When I do:**

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('feedback')->get();
```

It returns an array of all tickets with feedback in one array as expected.

**Next I want to get one ticket with all related feedback:**

```
$tickets = Ticket::find($id)->with('feedback')->get();
```

This returns also all tickets with their feedback.

**I tried:**

```
$tickets = Ticket::find($id)->with('feedback')->first();
```

This seems to work but ignores $id and always shows the first row/ticket in the table. $id is not empty, I checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` already runs a query. Then `with()->get()` runs another one without the where clause on the id. Do this instead:

```
$ticket = Ticket::with('feedback')->find($id);
```

Comment: If life could always be this simple! My thoughts where to complicated... I have a lot of learning left on Laravel ;-) Thanks!